# How do I continue current subscription until it ends and then switch plans in stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

The docs provides the code below, but I believe if I switch from a $10 / month membership to a $100 / year membership, it will make the switch immediately, and reduce the yearly package by the cost of any unused time from the original membership.

As there is no difference in content between the 2 packages, just an opportunity to save a bit of money by committing to a full year, I want the existing membership to continue until the month ends and then I want it to charge them the $100 and increase their billing cycle from monthly to yearly.

Does anyone know how to do this?
Here's the docs...

```
const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.retrieve('sub_49ty4767H20z6a');
stripe.subscriptions.update('sub_49ty4767H20z6a', {
  cancel_at_period_end: false,
  proration_behavior: 'create_prorations',
  items: [{
    id: subscription.items.data[0].id,
    price: 'price_CBb6IXqvTLXp3f',
  }]
});
```

Comment: What you can do is follow the example use case on [adding a SubscriptionSchedule to an existing Subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases#existing-subscription) and then add a second phase to the Schedule that starts when you want the Price to change.